# Dynamically changing my background image in django template from a database

Tags: django-templates

This is what I am using to change my background image:

```
<body id="bg" style="background-image: url( '{% static "polls/images/{{freetradezonedata.imagename}}"%}')">
```

When I go to my webpage and refresh this is what the console is looking for:

```
"GET /polls/static/polls/images/%7B%7Bfreetradezonedata.imagename%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 1781
```

The other substitutions from my database are happening in my html.

Is there a syntax change I can make or as etiing I can modify to make this work?

Should I try a different approach?

I did try using `{{MEDIA_URL}}{{freetradezonedata.imagename}}` from a different solution which resulted in:

> /polls/1/test/background.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 2943

It successfully substituted the image name but totally ignored the media_url portion of the path.

`media_url` was set to `MEDIA_URL = '/polls/static/polls/images/'`

Answer (score 0):

looking at other comments it occurred to me that nothing in static is going to have tags replaced.  so I tried coding just entering the last potion of my image path to see how it would render.  It worked, rendered as /polls/static/polls/images/background.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0